# Icon for new message button from iMessage

Tags: ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar

Where i can get icon from iMessage for creating new message button at navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download The UIKit artwork extractor for this. https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor
Then then run it on the retina iPhone simulator, and look for the message button (just search "send") then save it to your desktop. I also recommend to save all images as many of those images are very useful for all kinds of apps.

Answer (score 0):

i would not use officiall apple images in your apps - you might run into copyright problems (unless you buy the rights to use it).

i would advise you to create an icon yourself. if you really need that one, just make a screenshot with your iphone and copy it from there..